# Is this construction possible?

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to construct in an equilateral triangle $3$ congruent circles such that they're internally tangent to two sides of the triangle and shares a point of intersection between each other?

I've been trying to make such construction but i've miserably failed so far,so i was wondering if such construction is possible in general.

If it is,how do you construct it ?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: [image]

It should be something like that but with the exception that the three circles must have a point of intersection in common.

Comment: It would help to include a picture.

Comment: congruent circles? sounds strange to me, you mean equal probably?

Comment: @MikhailV  circles with same radius ,yes.

Comment: Each circle can only be tangent on 2 sides of the triangle? or can it be 3?

Comment: ok so make the circles bit smaller and they'll have common point in the center of triangle. No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\triangle{ABC}$ be an equilateral triangle.

- Get a point $D$ on the side $BC$ where $BD=\frac 13BC$. (Do you know how?)
- Draw the perpendicular line to the side $BC$ that passes through $D$. (call this line $L_1$)
- Draw an angle-bisector of $\angle{CBA}$. (call this line $L_2$)
- The intersection point between $L_1$ and $L_2$ is the center of one circle you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it without perpendiculars and without getting the 1/3 of the side.

1. Draw a circle and a same circle which goes through the center of the first one:

[image]

2. Connect the marked points with straight lines and you'll get something like this. Now you draw again the same circle (orange) at the point ***O*** and now you have automatically the centers of two other circles, which are intersections with other two circles (yellow) :

[image]

3. Now just draw two circles again at those centers and youre actually almost done:

[image]

---

To solve the task for a given triangle, I would do it so:

1. Construct the heights in each direction with big circles, which will also give the center of the triangle, then draw the circle around the triangle:

[image]

2. Connect the points from previous image and you'll get this, then draw again three lines (green) and you're done, here are the centers of the needed circles:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer @Mikhail ,also how would you go if you were to construct these same circles given a triangle ?that's harder to do.

Comment: @Nameless I've just realized it is even much simpler, updated again

Comment: Can you construct these same circles given a scalene triangle $\Delta ABC $ ?

Comment: @Nameless I don't think it is that easy, but it is interesting problem